# Can I import a separate blender file as a mesh?

Tags: modeling, blend-files

I'm not sure how to really word this question but I am trying to make a low poly model in blender and I'm thinking of trying to make certain parts in a separate file (primarily the hair, as it's supposed to be half-shaved and I feel as if making it separately would make it easier to do than trying to extrude everything.), but I am not entirely sure you can import other blender files as a mesh. If someone could also tell me how you would go about this that would be very helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can append in objects from other Blend files (*File > Append*)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial, stand on their own, and thoroughly explain the solution and required steps. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can, [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and how it works, perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating some steps and final result. See [How to write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), otherwise it may be converted to a comment.

Comment: For some reason the option is blacked out, is there something I'm missing? Even if I don't have a file to add then it should at least pop up showing there is no files to append.

Comment: You mean the append file is greyed out? Your probably in edit mode. Hit tab to get back into object mode

Comment: @quellemform I can't really think of Any thing else I need to add to the answer to improve it but I'm happy to change it to a comment